# Rspec error cannot find matching line from backtrace

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have written a group of 23 tests for my user model and all of them are failing with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace 
ArgumentError: 
  block not supplied
```

I have tried messing with different versions of capybara, rspec-rails, and growl, but to be perfectly honest, I really don't know what I'm doing here, and don't really understand the error.  I would really appreciate help from anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Here is a sample from my `user_spec.rb` file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before @user = User.new(name: 'example', password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar',
                        email: 'example@example.com', description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...')

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:description) }
  it { should respond_to(:admin) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Here are the relevant parts of my `Gemfile`:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-spork', :github => 'guard/guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
end
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you have not specified a block for the before method:

```
before @user = User.new(name: 'example', password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar',
                    email: 'example@example.com', description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...')
```

should be:

```
before do
  @user = User.new(name: 'example', password: 'foobar', password_confirmation: 'foobar',
                    email: 'example@example.com', description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor...')
end
```

Admittedly the error message is not very helpful here. The Ruby interpreter can't always pinpoint the exact line in the program that an error is raised, e.g. when there is a Stack level deep error' but I'm not sure why it cannot in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That stupid little syntax error was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was able to find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043426/error-comparison-of-symbol-with-module-failed-after-upgrading-to-rspec-3). Though in doesn't apply in this case, my problem was that Rails 3 doesn't allow symbols to name describe blocks, ie you have to have `describe 'create'` instead of `describe :create`.