# Error `comparison of Symbol with Module failed` after upgrading to Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I just upgraded from Rspec 2.99 to Rspec 3 and am getting the following error for some of my tests.

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
ArgumentError:
  comparison of Symbol with Module failed
```

I have the following controller test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PeopleController, type: :controller do
  subject { response }

  describe :index do
    before { get :index }

    it { should_not be_success }
    it { should have_http_status '401' }
  end
end
```

Any idea what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't use symbols after `describe` anymore. You need to replace

```
describe :index do
```

with

```
describe 'index' do
```

You are however able to use symbols as tags, for example...

```
describe 'index', :awesome do
  ...
end
```

Now when running the tests you can target only tests with a certain tag.

```
$ rspec --tag awesome
```